# Upgrading postgres to 10.3 from 9.6.3 does not update the psql server

Tags: postgresql

I had postgres 9.6.3 installed on my mac. I installed postgis version 2.3 through homebrew due to which my postgres also got updated to version 10.3. Then I uninstalled the previous version of postgres as well as tried created symlinks to the old version, but nothing seems to work here.

Right now my postgres is updated to 10.3 but when i run it on my local machine, it still shows server version 9.6.3. Here's the screenshot to that :

[image]

Can someone please help me how to go about this? I have already tried all the possible solutions available on stackoverflow but still no luck.